# Is 'denoisingNetwork' in 'denoiseImage' specific to one noise?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, deep-learning

What kind of noise removal training does the function 'denoisingNetwork' do, which is used as a part of 'denoiseImage'? Is it specific to some kind of noise and noise level or just a generalized network that gives an average output image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works only for gaussian noise, but with almost every level of noise.
It could be used to remove some other kind of noises, but that's not guaranteed. 
However if you look at Matlab documentation it says that uses a pre-trained model called "DnCNN". 
So i think that could be useful to see the relative paper: 
[link to paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.03981)

Comment: So the pre-trained model "DnCNN" denoises Gaussian noise at different noise levels?

Comment: If I'm executing customised training net, should I give different noise levels to different nets or can I do it with the same net? If I can do it with the same net, then should I give multiple noise levels as inputs while training and test over the dataset?

Comment: @unicornucopia sorry i don't understand what are you asking for. Can you please me explain better what is your objective and how you intend to complete it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask that if I want to write a customised network that does Gaussian denoising, then do I have to input images of different noise levels into the same network to train or would I have to train different networks to handle different noise levels? What would provide a better outcome, in terms of quality, speed and complexity?

Comment: @unicornucopia well i think the best option for you is a single network trained on different levels. This is due to two reasons: 1) Time complexity. Training a single network even if bigger should take you less time (unless it's too much bigger than the others). 2) If you train different networks you will have each network learn only to denoise that level of noise, so you could have problems when the noise level of your test photo is between one and another network. 
Of course training a single network that does denoising on different levels is not that simple.